# PDF import in inkscape : embedded clicable href links are lost during the process

Tags: pdf-generation, inkscape

Is there a known issue while importing pdf with clicable href links into inkscape ? Here all pre-existing links are lost in the process ...

I'm using XMIND to build pdf mindmaps. I'm trying to assemble several maps with inkscape into a larger diagramm that I want (at the end) to export in pdf. In XMIND I am exporting the maps in pd, and links are working.

Comment: The links may not be retained when importing PDFs in Inkscape. A merge request for internal linking in PDFs exists, which could be relevant to discuss there: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/merge_requests/5221